# Faking foreign key updates using entity keys

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-3.5

In [Alex James' Entity Framework tips articles](http://blogs.msdn.com/alexj/archive/2009/03/26/index-of-tips.aspx), (which are excellent by the way) he talks about [how to fake foreign key properties](http://blogs.msdn.com/alexj/archive/2009/03/25/tip-7-faking-foreign-key-properties-in-net-3-5-sp1.aspx). This seems like exactly what I need, but for whatever reason I can't seem to pull it off when I'm updating. I have the following in update portion of my controller:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Edit(candidates candidateToEdit)
    {
        string EduIDValue = candidateToEdit.education.ID.ToString();

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return View();

        try
        {
            var originalCandidate = (from c
                                            in model.candidates
                                            where c.ID == candidateToEdit.ID select c).FirstOrDefault();

            //attempting it here
            originalCandidate.educationReference.EntityKey = new System.Data.EntityKey("model.education", "ID", candidateToEdit.education.ID);

            model.ApplyPropertyChanges(originalCandidate.EntityKey.EntitySetName, candidateToEdit);                
            model.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Response.Write("Education ID Value " + EduIDValue + "<br /><br />Error: <br /><br />" + e);
            return null;                
            //return View();
        }
    }
```

This fails and spits out the following:

System.ArgumentException: The member with identity 'model' does not exist in the metadata collection. Parameter name: identity at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataCollection`1.GetValue(String identity, Boolean ignoreCase) at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.ReadOnlyMetadataCollection`1.GetValue(String identity, Boolean ignoreCase) at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.ItemCollection.GetEntityContainer(String name, Boolean ignoreCase) at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.ItemCollection.GetEntityContainer(String name) at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataWorkspace.GetEntityContainer(String name, DataSpace dataSpace) at System.Data.EntityKey.GetEntitySet(MetadataWorkspace metadataWorkspace) at System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityReference.set_EntityKey(EntityKey value) at InternshipTest.Controllers.CandidatesController.Edit(candidates candidateToEdit) in C:\Documents and Settings\graham\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\InternshipTest\InternshipTest\Controllers\CandidatesController.cs:line 84

Which doesn't make any sense to me, model is definitely the name of the EntitySet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out, I did in fact have the EntitySet incorrect. I got around it by passing the following as the first argument when creating a new entity key:

```
originalCandidate.educationReference.EntityKey = new System.Data.EntityKey(originalCandidate.educationReference.EntityKey.EntityContainerName + "." + originalCandidate.educationReference.EntityKey.EntitySetName, "ID", candidateToEdit.education.ID);
```

Kinda nasty, but it works.
Looking forward to the foreign key mess in EF being sorted out in .net 4.0

Comment: Glad you like the series. BTW there was a NULL reference exception bug in the blog post, which I just fixed.